# como puedo hacer para que la siguiente imagen no se deforme utilizando codigo css

Tags: html, css

Tengo un contenedor principal, con dos contenedores en linea posicionados con flex cada uno tiene su contenido, el problema es que el de la derecha quiero que la imagen crezca o decreca con el tamaño de la pantalla poniendo como limite de crecimiento su maximo width, esto normalmente me funciona si no esta dentro de ningun contenedor, pero con este caso aunque la imagen llegue al maximo de su tamaño no hace caso al max-width y sigue creciendo perdiendo su calidad de imagen.

Por si no he sido suficientemente claro el resultado que pretendo conseguir esque la imagen se amolde al tamaño del contenedor, pero cuando su ancho sea el tamaño de ancho de la imagen no quiero que crezca mas

Aqui os dejo el codigo, no he sabido subir la foto :( pero os digo el tamaño si os vale de algo 364 x 501

```css
img {
    display: block;
    max-width: 100%;
    width: 80%;
    height: auto;
    margin: 2rem auto;
}

.container {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    display: flex;
}



.mini-derecha {
    width: 50%;
    background-color: aqua;
    position: relative;
}

.cuadrado-alto{
    width: 100px;
    height: 1600px;
    background-color: red;
}

.mini-izquierda {
    width: 50%;
    background-color: darkgreen;
}

.cuadrados {
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    background-color: yellow;
    margin-top: 2rem;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="mini-container mini-izquierda">
            <div class="cuadrado-alto"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="mini-container mini-derecha">
            <img src="img/boton-paypal.jpg" alt="boton-paypal">
            <div class="cuadrados"></div>
            <div class="cuadrados"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si entiendo, lo que quieres es que la imagen no supere los 364 pixeles de ancho cuando el contenedor se agranda? si es asi lo logras con la propiedad max-width: 364px;

```css
img {
    display: block;
    max-width: 100%;
    width: 80%;
    height: auto;
    margin: 2rem auto;
}

.container {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    display: flex;
}
/* limita el ancho a su medida */
.mini-derecha img{
 max-width: 364px;
}

.mini-derecha {
    width: 50%;
    background-color: aqua;
    position: relative;
}

.cuadrado-alto{
    width: 100px;
    height: 1600px;
    background-color: red;
}

.mini-izquierda {
    width: 50%;
    background-color: darkgreen;
}

.cuadrados {
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    background-color: yellow;
    margin-top: 2rem;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="mini-container mini-izquierda">
            <div class="cuadrado-alto"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="mini-container mini-derecha">
            <img src="https://placeimg.com/364/501/any" alt="boton-paypal">
            <div class="cuadrados"></div>
            <div class="cuadrados"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```